# Summation of Trilinear form elements

Tags: linear-algebra

I know that $(a+b,c+d)=(a,c)+(a,d)+(b,c)+(b,d)$
But what for $(a+b,c+d,e+f)$? Am little confused although it's a very simple question. But can you pls put the general formula?

Comment: define $(a,b,c)$

Comment: Just iterate it. You know $g=(a+b,c+d)$. Then compute $(a+b,c+d,e+f)=(g,e+f)$.

Comment: $(a,c,e)+(a,c,f)+(a,d,e)+(a,d,f)+(b,c,e)+(b,c,f)+(b,d,e)+(b,d,f)$ isn"t it?